# Is it possible to create a big text for sending to telegram bot?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, telegram-bot

I've created a telegram bot. He has one mission to inform in group about new orders. When the customer create new order, telegram bot sends message with information that new order was created.
I use this api: ( Chat id and token are provided as an example)

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot449123456:AAHSAnSGDm8PW2Z-1ZiwdVDmgv7sM3NMTxg/sendMessage?chat_id=311911234&text=Hi+Everyone
```

All works fine, but how can I send not a simple text( with **+** as a whitespace) but a big text with information about order, and order cart?
I think I should use another method instead of simple call api...

Now, I am using nest js for backend, and yes, I know about telegraf and other npm packages, but because I use this bot only for send information from site, could I avoid additional packages and create a simple api call with big text? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please post sample message you want to send?

Comment: I believe you can. https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage. To make that `text` query, use [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you suggestion @micael-levi. I have found a method

1. To put my text into variable
2. To encode this variable with method **encodeURIComponent**
3. To Specify in API params that it is a HTML and it should be parsed as a HTML **(parse_mode=HTML)**